Generalization for Jensen's inequality for expected values
I'm trying to prove this. Let $\Phi$ be a convex function and X,Y random variables on the same probability space, where $Y \geq 0$ a.s. and $E(Y) = 1$. It holds $\Phi(E(XY)) \leq E(\Phi(X)Y)$.
What I tried: the standard jensen's inequality for X, Y and XY. This did not get me anywhere. I'm also not sure how to use $Y \geq 0$. Any help is appreciated.

With the assumptions on $Y$ the expectation $E(XY)$ is nothing else than the expectation $E_Q(X)$ under the probability measure $Q$ defined by $dQ/dP=Y,.$ Now apply Jensen to $\Phi(E_Q(X)),.$

Thanks, I think that's the answer I was looking for.

Do you mean by assumptions, absolute continuity Q << P? If so, why is it okay to assume this?

When $A$ is a $P$-null set don't we have $E_P[Y1_A]=0,?$ Then $Q(A)=0,.$

What is the context here?
Assume $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is convex and $E[XY]$ and $E[Y\phi(X)]$ are finite.
One approach (not the only one) is to create i.i.d. copies $\{(X_i,Y_i)\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$, each drawn according to the  joint distribution for $(X,Y)$. Since $E[Y]>0$, we must have $P[Y>0]>0$ and so
$$P[\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} \{Y_i>0\}]=1$$
Define the probability-1 event
$$ A = \left(\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}\{Y_i\geq 0\}\right)\cap \left( \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} \{Y_i>0\} \right) $$
Consider any outcome $\omega \in A$.
Let $M$ be the first index $i$ for which $Y_i>0$. Then by Jensen's inequality we have on a sample path basis that
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\phi(X_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^nY_i}\geq \phi\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_iY_i}{\sum_{i=1}^nY_i}\right) \quad \forall n \geq M$$
This is because
$$\frac{(Y_1, ..., Y_n)}{\sum_{i=1}^nY_i}$$
can be viewed as a PMF over which you are averaging the $X_i$ samples. This is where we are using the fact that $Y_i\geq 0$ for all $i$ (and at least one $Y_i$ is positive).  Then we can use the law of large numbers and continuity of $\phi$.

Another way (which may be simpler than my previous i.i.d. answer):
Assume $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is convex. Assuming expectations are finite, define $z\in\mathbb{R}^n$ by
$$z = \frac{E[XY]}{E[Y]}$$
Define $\phi'(z)$ as a subgradient at $z$ and use the subgradient inequality
$$ \phi(x) \geq \phi(z) + \phi'(z)^{\top}(x-z)\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$$
Therefore
$$ \phi(X) \geq \phi(z) + \phi'(z)^{\top}(X-z)$$
Now multiply both sides by the nonnegative random variable $Y$. This proof works whenever expectations are finite, $Y$ is nonnegative, and $E[Y]>0$, to conclude
$$ \frac{E[Y\phi(X)]}{E[Y]} \geq \phi\left( \frac{E[YX]}{E[Y]}\right)$$
